# Batch file to delete files and folders in user directories

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to delete some files and folders in users' directories.  Here is what it looks like.  I have some user accounts in C:\Users\ like 'Bob' and 'Joe'.  In each of those directories, I want to delete some folders and files. So the architecture looks like this and my script now is below that:

I am trying to delete the files in \Temp\ and trying to delete the whole directory.  Any ideas?  I am also trying to have the script work if another user name was added.  Thanks

Comment: I don't see a question here, so I assume that "it isn't working." What should it be doing, and what is it actually doing? Are no files being deleted? Are the folders not being deleted? Did you completely format your hard drive by accident?

Comment: Also, remember that inside of scripts, `for` loop variables need two `%` symbols, so `%m` should be `%%m`.

Comment: @SomethingDark, sorry that is correct.  This is not working properly.  Thanks for the info, I will add the extra %

Comment: My initial question still stands - which _specific_ part of your code is not working the way it should be?

Comment: Well, adding the extra % helped.  Now it looks like the line with `del /Q /F` is deleting the files in that folder that I want.  But I also what it to delete any folders that reside in \Temp\.  Not sure what command would do that

Comment: Use `rd /s` like you did in the other line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
FOR /D %%p IN ("%file path goes here%*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q

To delete the folder change %file path goes here% to the file path of that folder and remove the % signs

Answer (score 0):

Let's expand this a bit.

```
for /r "d:\Program Files\Logs\Logs" %%a in (*.zip) do (
    for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
      if /i "%%~nxb" == "Special" (
         forfiles /p "%%~dpa." /m "%%~nxa" /d -60 /c "cmd /c del @path && echo @path was deleted"
         ) else (
         forfiles /p "%%~dpa." /m "%%~nxa" /d -30  /c "cmd /c del @path && echo @path was deleted"
        )
     )
 )
```

You could expand this to include your temp folders:

```
for /r "c:\users" %%a in (*.*) do (
    for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
      if /i "%%~dpa" == "temp" (
         forfiles /p "%%~dpa." /m "%%~nxa" /c "cmd /c rd /q/s @path"
         ) else (
         forfiles /p "%%~dpa." /m "%%~nxa" /c "cmd /c del @path"
        )
     )
 )
```

Note: The RD /q /s and if you use for /? you will get the variable substitution for the %~dpa and such.

Hope this helps!